# Problem with data extraction from Indeed by BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I'm trying to extract job descriptions for each post from Indeed website but, the result is not what I expected!

I've written a code to get job descriptions. I'm working with python 2.7 and the latest beautifulsoup. When you open the page and click on each job title, you will see the related information on the right side of the screen. I need to extract those job descriptions for each job on this page. My Code:

```
import sys

import urllib2 

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=construction%20manager&l=Houston%2C%20TX&vjk=8000b2656aae5c08"

html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

N = soup.findAll("div", {"id" : "vjs-desc"})

print N
```

I expected to see the results but instead, I got [] as the result. Is it because the Id is non-unique. If so, how should I edit the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `#vjs-desc` element is generated by javascript and the content are from Ajax request. To get the description you need to do that request.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# it easier to create http request/session using this
import requests
import re, urllib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www......"

# create session
s = requests.session()
html = s.get(url).text

# exctract job IDs
job_ids = ','.join(re.findall(r"jobKeysWithInfo\['(.+?)'\]", html))
ajax_url = 'https://www.indeed.com/rpc/jobdescs?jks=' + urllib.quote(job_ids)
# do Ajax request and convert the response to json 
ajax_content = s.get(ajax_url).json()
print(ajax_content)

for id, desc in ajax_content.items():
    print id
    soup = BeautifulSoup(desc, 'html.parser')
    # or try this
    # soup = BeautifulSoup(desc.decode('unicode-escape'), 'html.parser')
    print soup.text.encode('utf-8')
    print('==============================')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I got this error message:   soup = BeautifulSoup(desc.decode('unicode-escape'), 'html.parser')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 609: ordinal not in range(128) @ewwink

Comment: I added import urllib at the begining and I removed what you asked for but still  got another error: File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\BeautifulSoup.py", line 1344, in unknown_starttag
    and (self.parseOnlyThese.text or not self.parseOnlyThese.searchTag(name, attrs)):
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'     @ewwink

Comment: but it print partial result right? try adding `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at first line and add again `.decode('unicode-escape')`

Comment: No partial results, unfortunately. Where do you mean by at first line? where should I add your last comment? @ewwink

Comment: answer edited, take a look, consider using python 3 because python 2.7 sometimes has problem with character encoding.

Comment: AWESOME! Thanks for the code, it works! Would you please tell me how should I proceed to define a loop which helps me to get the data from next pages? Regards.

Comment: page 2 append `&start=10` to the search URL, page 3 `&start=20` and so on